# bash: crw-rw----: command not found

Tags: bash, command-not-found

I am currently trying to build a LIDAR robot with RPLIDAR A1 and Jetson Nano following the guide below.

https://www.hackster.io/shahizat005/building-a-map-using-lidar-with-ros-melodic-on-jetson-nano-2f92dd

I have reached step 8 where I'm trying to initialize the USB port to connect the robot with the LIDAR. However, upon running

`ls -l /dev | grep ttyUSB`

I did not get any output, which I assume is not normal as ls should show the files in that directory from my understanding.

After that, I ran

`crw-rw----`

As it have stated in the guide. It should have outputs, however, an error occurred as follows.

`bash: crw-rw----: command not found`

Does anyone know how to fix this as I am new to the linux development environment? Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  0 Oct 30 18:10 ttyUSB0
```

is meant to be the output of the *previous*

```
ls -l /dev | grep ttyUSB
```

command (which will give a report of the metadata including permissions for all the files in `/dev` whose name or symlink target contains `ttyUSB`), not a command you're meant to run. You just need to verify that you get a similar output and note the exact name of the ttyUSB device file that corresponds to your USB device.

Then it tells you to run the `chmod 666` command on that file after which the first field in the `ls -l` output should look like `crw-rw-rw-`.

Now, making a system file world writeable (here device file) is not a wise thing to do. That's a shortcut  that has security implications and will likely be lost the next time you reboot or unplug the USB device. I don't know the details of that system they're documenting, but I'd expect a better solution would be to add the user that's meant to  interact with that device into the `dialout` group.